# Creating a CMYK figure in EPS or TIFF in R

Tags: r, rgb, tiff, eps, cmyk

Good morning

I am using `R` (with `ggplot`)

A journal I am submitting to wants graphics files in either TIFF or EPS and using CMYK (not RGB). Searching around, I found that there is `colormodel` in `PDF` but not in 'TIFF`. Typing ?eps found nothing, and ??eps led me to`postscript`which does have`colormodel` but produces .ps files. Are these the same as .eps files?

What should I substitute for my current code which is

```
jpeg(file = 'c:\\PATH\\FILE.jpg')
   plotname
dev.off()
```

TIA

Answer (score 4, accepted):

eps is an encapsuled postscript document (see [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Encapsulated_PostScript)). The most important difference that an eps image contains a BoundingBox.

You can save an eps file using `postscript`:

```
postscript('file.eps', colormodel="cmyk")
plot(1:10, 1:10)
dev.off()
```

Does that help?

Comment: Hi - is there any way to do this with .TIFF files? I've run in to the same problem as @PeterFlom but can't get it to work with TIFF. Also I get a warning, because I'm using "serif" as my font...any pointers would be truely helpful. Cheers.